# Verifying a JNA structure using mockito

Tags: java, mockito, jna

When testing a native call using JNA we can use Mockito as we would for any other Java code.

However if we are passing structures to the native layer things are a little trickier - two JNA structures are considered equal if the data **and** the memory pointers are equal.

For example, if we have the following trivial library:

```java
class SomeStructure extends Structure {
    ....
}

interface SomeLibrary {
    void someMethod(SomeStructure struct);
}
```

and we exercise the method as follows:

```java
SomeLibrary lib = Mockito.mock(SomeLibrary.class);
SomeStructure struct = new SomeStructure();
lib.someMethod(struct);
```

then the following test will fail even though the code actually works:

```java
SomeStructure expected = new SomeStructure();
Mockito.verify(lib).someMethod(expected);
```

Mockito compares actual against expected values using `equals`, but this is over-ridden in the JNA structure base-class to also compare the underlying native pointers.  I assume there are reasons for this behaviour (certainly the `equals` method is used in a couple of places within the JNA framework).

More simply:

```java
assertTrue(new SomeStructure().equals(new SomeStructure()));     // Fails!!!
```

One work-around is to use a Mockito `ArgumentCaptor` to retrieve the actual structure that was passed to `verify` and test the relevant fields.

Another is to over-ride the `equals` implementation of the structure (the test version only!) to delegate to `dataEquals` (for example).

A third is to implement a custom Mockito argument matcher that over-rides the over-ride.

All of these just add more boiler-plate to the unit-test.  In particular using captors and matchers obfuscates the test because we have to start wrapping all the arguments as matchers.

Is there any simpler way of doing this?

NOTE: Obviously the above example would hardly be worth the trouble since all it would achieve is testing Mockito, in reality the application code will be applying logic, populating structures, making various native calls, etc.

Comment: You saying "then the following test will fail" I don't see why? It should pass. You testing for same instance that you passed to your mock. Are you sure it is failing?

Comment: @talex Edited the question to make it explicit that it's comparing two instances just as you commented!

Comment: What exactly you want to test? If `equals` doesn't work for you, you have to resort to `ArgCaptor` or custom matcher.

Comment: @talex Maybe the example I posted isn't very clear (?), but basically I just want to be able to `Mockito::verify` that a JNA structure was passed to a native method.  As you can see that can't be done - JNA structures are NOT equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there a simpler way of doing this?"  No.

You've pointed out that verify checks for equality of arguments.  You have outlined the possibilities:

- Pass the same argument
- Override the Structure so `equals()` behaves as you want
- Indirectly verify with a custom argument matcher.

I'd suggest the third route is probably the least intrusive, checking a different argument associated with the structure in which `equals()` matches.

JNA Structure field values are directly tied to the underlying native bytes.  So comparing structure equality is as simple as comparing the bytes to each other, either as a byte array, or as a hex string (`dump()` can produce that).

First step: confirm native bytes are synchronized with the Java structure.  This depends on how you personally want to define "equality" for a structure that is represented both in a Java object and in native memory.

If you've just read it from native you should be good, otherwise you may need to `read()`; if you have manually manipulated the structure values in Java you may need to `write()` before comparing equality.

After that, just get the backing bytes. Assuming your structure variables are `foo` and `bar`:

```java
byte[] fooStructureBytes = foo.getByteArray(0, foo.size());
byte[] barStructureBytes = bar.getByteArray(0, bar.size());
// In JUnit terms
assertArrayEquals(fooStructureBytes, barStructureBytes);
// In Mockito, you'll do something similar where you track "expected" in terms of bytes and compare vs. the bytes of your actual structure.
```

If you're doing a lot of this, you might want to generalize the above steps in a custom assertion in your test framework so you can just `assertStructureEquals(foo, bar)`.

The above is simplified for the purpose of this answer and assumes the structures are of the same class type and have the same alignment.  If you're generalizing this you might want to make a few more tests (similar to how you'd write an `equals()`) to be more robust.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation which makes it clear how two JNA structures can be considered 'equal' (depending on ones definition of 'equal').  However I don't think that helps with the case I was trying to illustrate where we call `Mockito::verify` which explicitly depends on standard Java equality.  i.e. we are still stuck with having to implement some indirection to do the byte-array comparison rather than a standard Java equality test - unless I'm missing the point?

Comment: Not overly familiar with Mockito, but was offering a shortcut to iterating through all the fields and comparing them.  Does Mockito truly not offer an equivalent of `assertArrayEquals()`?  I suppose you could convert the byte array to a String and compare String equality.

Comment: If Mockito truly doesn't have the flexibility to consider any trivial manipulations as I've described, then it seems overriding `equals()` is the only sane approach.

Comment: Yes Mockito can assert an array is equal but that isn't the problem per-se.  The issue is that the stubbing and mocking methods (when, verify) match method arguments by equals comparison.  So in my example I am forced to jump through more hoops just to make the actual JNA structure argument equal the expected values (such as overriding the equals method, using a captor, etc).  Oh well!

Comment: I've updated the preface to my answer to explain a little bit more why I answered the way I did.